# how to set font for a tab title in jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have designed a `tabbedpane` which includes some tabs, is there any way to set a font for the titles of tabs? 
I have read [this useful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260484/java-swing-how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-jpanels-titledborder) however through this approach we can only set the title of border and not the title of a tab.

A simple code to explain my problem:

```
private  JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
private  JPanel tab1;
private  Jpanel tab2;
...
tabbedPane.insert("title1", icon1, tab1, "tip1", 0);
tabbedPane.insert("title2", icon2, tab2, "tip2", 1);
```

How can I change the font of "title1" or "title2" ?

---

**Edit:**

According to answer of Dear `Jay Smith`, I realized that this approach is more powerful, however I have some other problem, see this picture please:

[image]

I am create a JPanel (i.e. called myPanel) for each tab which consist of two JLabel, one for TabIcon and another for TabTitle. finally, I have writed this:

```
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, myPanel);
```

Now, what are problems:

1. First of all, notice that I am using persian language which is a
   right to left, so I want to pull icon to the leftmost position and
   the tabTitle to the rightmost position.
2. Second, according to the border of first tab, I want that panel fill
   entire space of tabHeader.

Comment: `UIManager.getDefaults().getFont("TabbedPane.font")` is one brute force method, if you need more customisation/control, then you'd need to supply your own custom title component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is too easy my friend. Do the following and you are through.

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setFont( new Font( "Dialog", Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC, 24 ) );
```

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set any Swing `Component` as tab in `JTabbedPane`.

Example of `JLabel` as tab:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Tab 1");
label.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 24));

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, label);
```

Comment: your approach is elegant and very powerful, but I have some new problems with alignment, orientation and filling the parent component. please see the question I have edited.

Comment: @Tot Zam please revise the edit part of the question.